# Moving non-Copy variable into async closure: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to get [clokwerk](https://crates.io/crates/clokwerk) to schedule an asynchronous function to run every X seconds.

[The docs](https://docs.rs/clokwerk/0.4.0-rc1/clokwerk/struct.AsyncScheduler.html) show this example:

```
// Create a new scheduler
let mut scheduler = AsyncScheduler::new();
// Add some tasks to it
scheduler
    .every(10.minutes())
        .plus(30.seconds())
    .run(|| async { println!("Simplest is just using an async block"); });
// Spawn a task to run it forever
tokio::spawn(async move {
  loop {
    scheduler.run_pending().await;
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
  }
});
```

My initial attempt:

```
    let config2 = // define a Config struct, Config
    let pg_pool2 = // get a sqlx connection pool, Pool<Postgres>

    //I assume I need shared references so I use Arc
    let pg_pool2 = Arc::new(pg_pool2);
    let config2 = Arc::new(config2);

    let mut scheduler = AsyncScheduler::new();

    scheduler.every(5.seconds()).run(|| async {
        println!("working!");
        pull_from_main(pg_pool2.clone(), config2.clone()).await;
    });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            scheduler.run_pending().await;
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    });
```

The compiler complains that `pg_pool2` and `config2` may outlive the borrowed value, and suggests to add `move`. Fair. Let's try that.

My second attempt:

```
    //rest the same
    scheduler.every(5.seconds()).run(move || async {
    //rest the same
```

This time I get back an error I can't decipher on my own:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:80:46
   |
75 |       let pg_pool2 = Arc::new(pg_pool2);
   |           -------- variable defined here
...
80 |       scheduler.every(5.seconds()).run(move || async {
   |  ____________________________________________-_^
   | |                                            |
   | |                                            inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
81 | |         println!("working!");
82 | |         pull_from_main(pg_pool2.clone(), config2.clone()).await;
   | |                        -------- variable captured here
83 | |     });
   | |_____^ returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Can someone help me understand what's wrong and how to fix it?

Note: I've seen this question asked before, but I'm struggling to apply the answers to my case.

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266516/why-i-get-error-captured-variable-cannot-escape-fnmut-closure-body) a mutable variable is involved, which I don't have.
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557219/error-on-future-generator-closure-captured-variable-cannot-escape-fnmut-closu) the solution is to include the variable as a fn argument, which I can't do as the closure expects no arguments. It also seems to return a value from the closure, which is causing the problem, when I don't.

I'm also a beginner so maybe they do apply, but I don't see the connection:)

Comment: HS: "I'm also a beginner" tokio and async world in general is NOT advice to rust  beginner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to understand what's going on, I'll reformat the code a bit in order to make it more clear and explicit:

Your original code:

```rust
  scheduler
    .every(5.seconds())
    .run(move || async {
        do_something(arc.clone());
    });
```

Is equivalent to:

```rust
  scheduler
    .every(5.seconds())
    .run(move || {
       return async {
          do_something(arc.clone());
       }
    });
```

So you create a closure, which is of type `FnMut` (and which returns a type that implements `Future`). That means that your closure can be called multiple times, and each invocation should produce a new future. But `return async{}` **moves** your `Arc` out of the closure, which means that it can be called only once. Imagine that you have a 10$ note in your wallet. If you take it out and spend it, then you will not be able to take it out and spend it for a second time, because it's simply not there anymore.

So how can we solve that ? It's pretty easy actually - you have to clone your `Arc` before moving it to the `async` block. Thus you will move only the clone:

```rust
    let arc = Arc::new(whatever);   
    scheduler
        .every(5.seconds())
        .run(move || {
             // Clone the arc and move the clone!!! 
             // The original arc will remain in the closure, 
             // so it can be called multiple times.
            let x = arc.clone(); 
            async move { 
                do_something(x);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple explanation! Also I finally understand the difference between "async move || .." and "move || async ..". Thanks dude!

Comment: Good explanation, helped me a lot.