# What does `move occurs due to use in generator` error mean?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I'm having this problem about generators:

```
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub fn run(f: Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<(), ()> + Send>) {
    f();
}

fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(0);
    run(Box::new(move ||{
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
        let _t = rt.block_on(async move {
            let y = x;
        });
        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de28ecf9e5baf6a017cd6a5230d74d7b

Error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `x`, a captured variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:13:41
   |
10 |       let x = Arc::new(0);
   |           - captured outer variable
...
13 |           let _t = rt.block_on(async move {
   |  _________________________________________^
14 | |             let y = x;
   | |                     -
   | |                     |
   | |                     move occurs because `x` has type `Arc<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   | |                     move occurs due to use in generator
15 | |         });
   | |_________^ move out of `x` occurs here
```

I don't understand why `x` is borrowed, if in both the closure and the block, I use `move`. So `x` should be moved to `rt.block_on`'s closure. There should be no borrow at all.

Comment: For solutions, is `impl FnOnce() -> F` an option for you instead?

Comment: @loganfsmyth please take a look at my update, I was able to come up with a better example of my problem. I cannot use `FnOnce`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67960931/moving-non-copy-variable-into-async-closure-captured-variable-cannot-escape-fn/67961594#67961594

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Generators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html) are an unstable feature, currently only available in nightly, which can be compared to generators or coroutines in other languages (e.g. [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#generator_functions), [Go](https://golangbot.com/goroutines/), [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)).

Generators are essentially state machines that can pause execution using `yield` and later be resumed again, with the possibility of passing data in each transition. This pattern is ideal for asynchronous programming and the Rust compiler expands certain `async` code to use generators, even though you can't explicitly use them yourself without the nightly feature enabled.

It is possible that it is a bug that these messages are not properly feature-gated, or it may just have been too complicated to present different errors for code generated from `async` desugaring than for code you explicitly wrote yourself.

So let's ignore generators, which are a bit of a red herring for your actual problem.

You are moving `x` into a closure:

```
let x = Arc::new(0);
run(Box::new(move ||{
    // 'move' closure uses x so x is moved
}));
```

And then the closure moves `x` again into an `async` block. The problem is that the signature of `run` accepts a `Fn` closure - a closure that cannot modify its environment but *may* be called multiple times. However the closure you have provided moves `x` into the `async` block the first time it's called, so it would be invalid to call it a second time.

Given you have said that you can't change `run` to accept an `FnOnce`, you need to make `f` callable multiple times by preventing it from moving `x`. You can do that by cloning it:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(0);
    run(Box::new(move || {
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
        // each time the closure is called, it will pass a clone of the Arc
        // into the task, so it can be called more than once
        let x = x.clone();
        let _t = rt.block_on(async move {
            let y = x;
        });
        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

The whole design of `Arc` is about cheap cloning. It's cheap because it only copies the pointer to your data and increments the reference count, which is how it knows when it is safe to free the memory of the holding its data. If you are never cloning an `Arc` then you almost certainly didn't need it in the first place!

Comment: how can the 'closure' (it's actually a block, right?) get a clone? When do I know if a clone will be send or a move will occur?

Comment: There are both. There is a closure that you pass to `run` and an async block (aka a task) which the closure creates and runs.

Comment: @HAL9000 Which string?

Comment: @PeterHall in this example you have an Arc but I'm having the same problem with a String. I just find a bit frustrating all this complexity for such a simple scenario. It's a complain about the language, not about your solution, don't take it personally

Answer (score 3):

The "move occurs due to use in generator" error seems to confuse things a bit here, but the overall issue isn't related to generators.

Your `run` function accepts `Fn()` functions, not `FnOnce()` functions. That means that the function passed to `run` must be able to execute multiple times. Given that, your code cannot work as written because running your function takes ownership of `x` when assigning it to `y`. If the first call to the function takes ownership of `x`, what is supposed to happen the second time the function runs? Ownership of `x` was already given to the future the first time it executed, and two things cant own the same value. The same issue would also happen with

```
run(Box::new(move ||{
    let y = x;
    Ok(())
}));
```

Since you have an `Arc` I'm guessing you had a sense of this already, but it won't happen without a bit more logic. Since you're using an `Arc`, you need to clone `x` at the start of the function, so that each time the function runs, it gets its own Arc object to handle and manipulate.

```
fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(0);
    run(Box::new(move ||{

        // Make a new Arc that can be given to the promise without needing
        // to worry about what future calls to this callback willl do.
        let x = Arc::clone(&x);

        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
        let _t = rt.block_on(async move {
            let y = x;
        });
        Ok(())
    }));
}
```